# Element tree parsing

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm totally new to element tree and I've been trying to change some text in an xml file. I've been reading some examples, but I can't seem to find examples that have the same kind of xml structure as the one I am trying to edit.

The specific element I am trying to access is one of many AvClass elements and looks like this..

```
<AvClass id="MMpr">
  <AvProp id="ASET" name="name" type="string">Untitled</AvProp>
  <AvProp id="ASET" name="kind" type="string">Interplay Folder</AvProp>
  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attributes" type="int16">17</AvProp>
  <AvProp id="ASET" name="type" type="int16">32</AvProp>
  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attrList" type="reference">
    <AvClass id="ATTR">
      <AvProp id="ATTR" name="__OMFI:ATTR:NumItems" type="int32">3</AvProp>
      <List id="OMFI:ATTR:AttrRefs">
        <ListElem>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">2</AvProp>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME</AvProp>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute" type="string">Projects//Post//Grading</AvProp>
        </ListElem>
        <ListElem>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_APPEND_PROJECT</AvProp>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">1</AvProp>
        </ListElem>
        <ListElem>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_VERIFY_DIRECTORY</AvProp>
          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">0</AvProp>
        </ListElem>
        <ListElem/>
      </List>
    </AvClass>
  </AvProp>
</AvClass>
```

The id="MMpr" is unique and contains a ListElem - ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME - which has a string 'Projects//Post//Grading'.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to post an example of code:

I want to change this string to something like 'Projects//NEW//STRING//ETC' and I'm struggling to get at it. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

ATM. I'm using a lot of for loops and comparison operators, but I'm really sure that there is an elegant way to do it.

```
tree = ET.parse(this_file) # create tree from file
root = tree.getroot() # set the root     
for x in root.iter('AvClass'): # iterates thru ALL classes    
        for prop in x: # get 1st level properties of class

            # Interplay Paths
            for chi1 in prop: # child of prop
                for chi2 in chi1: # child of child
                    if 'ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME' in str(chi2.text):
                        print(chi2.text)
                        #chi2.text = 'Projects//NEW//STRING//ETC'
```

I want to change the next AvProp elements text value in the list (which might be empty)

Comment: Where is your minimal code example that fails to what you want?

Comment: *to change this string* - change with  what?

Comment: I updated the question to include some ugly code and an example as suggested here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ye olde xpath.

Since you know your target string you can identify the `AvProp` element using it. In this code, having done that I verify that I can see the text then I assign new text to the element. Finally I display the complete new version of the xml.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('this_file.xml')
>>> avprop = tree.xpath('.//AvProp[text()="ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME"]')[0]
>>> avprop.text
'ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME'
>>> avprop.text = 'SOMETHING REALLY NOTICEABLE'
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
b'<AvClass id="MMpr">\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="name" type="string">Untitled</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="kind" type="string">Interplay Folder</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attributes" type="int16">17</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="type" type="int16">32</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attrList" type="reference">\n    <AvClass id="ATTR">\n      <AvProp id="ATTR" name="__OMFI:ATTR:NumItems" type="int32">3</AvProp>\n      <List id="OMFI:ATTR:AttrRefs">\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">2</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">SOMETHING REALLY NOTICEABLE</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute" type="string">Projects//Post//Grading</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_APPEND_PROJECT</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_VERIFY_DIRECTORY</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">0</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem/>\n      </List>\n    </AvClass>\n  </AvProp>\n</AvClass>'
```

Edit: Although the input file makes it appear that siblings follow one another in particular orders you cannot assume order when processing xml. In other words, siblings might be passed to a program in any order.

If I understand you correctly this time this seems to do the job.

This time, having identified the known element, I get its parent then look amongst its children for one that has the desired `name` attribute. If none of the children meets this requirement then `elements` will be an empty list. Otherwise, only the first item in the list will be the one whose content is to change.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('this_file.xml')
>>> elements = tree.xpath('.//AvProp[text()="ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME"]/../*[@name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute"]')
>>> elements[0].text
'Projects//Post//Grading'
>>> if elements:
...     elements[0].text = '*** SOMETING I CAN SEE EASILY ***'
...     
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
b'<AvClass id="MMpr">\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="name" type="string">Untitled</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="kind" type="string">Interplay Folder</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attributes" type="int16">17</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="type" type="int16">32</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attrList" type="reference">\n    <AvClass id="ATTR">\n      <AvProp id="ATTR" name="__OMFI:ATTR:NumItems" type="int32">3</AvProp>\n      <List id="OMFI:ATTR:AttrRefs">\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">2</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute" type="string">*** SOMETING I CAN SEE EASILY ***</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_APPEND_PROJECT</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_VERIFY_DIRECTORY</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">0</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem/>\n      </List>\n    </AvClass>\n  </AvProp>\n</AvClass>'
```

Then, to verify that the code is able to process an xml file in which that element is missing I 'commented out' the element and re-executed the code. This time the attempt to execute `elements[0].text` (something you would not do in production code) fails, as would be expected, and the xml remains unchanged.

```
>>> tree = etree.parse('this_file.xml')
>>> elements = tree.xpath('.//AvProp[text()="ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME"]/../*[@name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute"]')
>>> elements[0].text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> if elements:
...     elements[0].text = '*** SOMETING I CAN SEE EASILY ***'
... 
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
b'<AvClass id="MMpr">\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="name" type="string">Untitled</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="kind" type="string">Interplay Folder</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attributes" type="int16">17</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="type" type="int16">32</AvProp>\n  <AvProp id="ASET" name="attrList" type="reference">\n    <AvClass id="ATTR">\n      <AvProp id="ATTR" name="__OMFI:ATTR:NumItems" type="int32">3</AvProp>\n      <List id="OMFI:ATTR:AttrRefs">\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">2</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME</AvProp>\n          <!-- AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute" type="string">Projects//Post//Grading</AvProp -->\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_APPEND_PROJECT</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Kind" type="int32">1</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:Name" type="string">ATS_MM_VERIFY_DIRECTORY</AvProp>\n          <AvProp id="ATTR" name="OMFI:ATTB:IntAttribute" type="int32">0</AvProp>\n        </ListElem>\n        <ListElem/>\n      </List>\n    </AvClass>\n  </AvProp>\n</AvClass>'
```

Comment: Hi Bill, This will change the ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME identifier itself, which is the 2nd AvProp of the ListElem. The actual string/setting that needs to be changed is stored in the 3rd AvProp of the ListElem - 'Projects//Post//Grading' - which is a path of sorts. ATM I'm looking for part of this string. finding and changing it, but it might also be empty at some point. ie. the PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME setting might not be set. So I need a way to find the PDName AvProp identifier, and then change the next AvProp.text string in the ListElem. Do this make sense?

Comment: Thanks - that's the answer Bill, the way to find it by tree.xpath('.//AvProp[text()="ATS_MM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME"]/../*[@name="OMFI:ATTB:StringAttribute"]') was what was needed.